How can I safely write an UPDATE statement to update missing values from TABLE2?
I am in the middle of fix some bad data and I am looking a safer way to update a given column when the value does not exists anymore in it is related table.
Take a look to the following example (fiddle here):
-- SET sql_mode = '';

create table if not exists table1
(
    id                           int auto_increment primary key,
    table2_id int
);

create table if not exists table2
(
    id                           int auto_increment primary key
);


INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(1), (2);

SELECT * FROM table1;
SELECT * FROM table2;

SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.table2_id = table2.id;

the latest query from above will return just 2 rows because table2 does not have ids: 3, 4, 5. Then I need to write an UPDATE for table1 to set ids: 3, 4, 5 to NULL.
Can I get some ideas?

INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE... might be a solution.

I will suggest using NOT EXISTS, usually it will be more performant than using LEFT JOIN
UPDATE table1 t1 
SET t1.table2_id = null 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from table2 t2 WHERE t2.id=t1.table2_id)

See example

LEFT JOIN is another option.
UPDATE table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON  t1.table2_id = t2.id
SET t1.table2_id = NULL 
WHERE t2.id IS NULL

See example
Edit
Answer was changed from recommending LEFT JOIN to recommending NOT EXISTS
Detailed test can be found on MySQL: NOT EXISTS vs LEFT OUTER JOIN...IS NULL

What's wrong with:
update table1 set id = null where table2_id not in (select id from table2);
(note NOT IN is only a safe option if subquery column is not nullable)
I would also suggest adding a foreign key constraint once the data has been tidied up, to prevent the bad data from creeping back again

heh I guess nothing ... it was easy but for some reason I was trying to make it harder on my mind. Thx
